# Access $this from PHP outside of Magento

Tags: magento-1.8, php

I am playing around with the Mini Cart content from outside of Magento.

This section of code uses `$this`:

```
<?php foreach($cartItems as $_item): ?>
    <?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

`get_class($this)` tells me that it is using `Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Sidebar`

How can I access this?

For example I know you can replace `$this` with `Mage::helper('checkout/cart')`, is there an equivalent for `Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Sidebar`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('checkout/cart_sidebar')->getItemHtml($item);
```

but this may not work in this case because item rendering requires a set of renderers attached to the main block.

Comment: Genius.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Though its not god way But you can use outside you can create object via below code and you can use it.

```
$class = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('checkout/cart_sidebar');
$class->getItemHtml($_item);
```

Comment: you should never instantiate classes using `new`. Specially blocks. Blocks need to have a layout instance associated to them.

Comment: Ok I will update My answer